# Validation messages showing translations problems with cakephp

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I'm trying to internationalize my project with cakephp validation messages. The file generation .pot and later .po seems to be correct, the problem is when in the view the validation error is shown, the default message (written on the model) is always shown, do not get the message language file.

I tried two ways to extract messages:

```
cake i18n extract
OR
cake i18n extract --validation-domain validation
```

In my AppController I have:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'spa');
}
```

In my Locale directory I have:

```
Locale / spa / LC_MESSAGES / default.po
                             validation.po
```

In my PostModel I have:

```
class Post extends AppModel {

 public $validationDomain = "validation";

  public $validate = array(
    'text' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => '* Aquest camp és obligatori' //* This field is required -> in spanish -> Este campo es obligatorio            
        )
    )
  ); 
}
```

---

I'm using [**JqueryValidationHelper.php**](https://github.com/vz28bh/CakePHP-JqueryValidationHelper) and I create the inputs like this:

```
<?php echo $this->jQueryValidation->input('text', array('required'));?>
```

I missing something?? I have to tell cakephp where my validation messages are?? All the messages in default.po are shown correctly, I don't know what's going on whith validation messages...

Thanks

---

### **SOLUTION**

I edit the row in the file `JqueryValidationHelper`and the method `meta()`:

```
if (!empty($validateParams['message'])) {
    $msg = $validateParams['message'];
}
```

for

```
 if (!empty($validateParams['message'])) {
        $msg = __d('validation',$validateParams['message']);
 }
```

Take care to use `__d()` or `__()` depending how you extract you messages in `cake i18n extract` (in default.po) or if you define a `public $validationDomain = "validation";` in your Models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the source, the helper doesn't respect translations, it just grabs the raw values defined in the validation rules, see [**JqueryValidationHelper::meta()**](https://github.com/vz28bh/CakePHP-JqueryValidationHelper/blob/07b2ed4788bd5e18750ec81781626b4eac728912/JqueryValidationHelper.php#L149).

I'd suggest to create an issue ticket and request for adding proper translation support as can be seen in [**CakeValidationSet::_processValidationResponse()**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.5/lib/Cake/Model/Validator/CakeValidationSet.php#L256). Or just add it yourself...

Comment: Thanks @ndm finally I have made it work! I edit `JqueryValidationHelper::meta()` adding support for translation. I edit my answer with the solution. Thank you!